# Indexing variables in R

Tags: r, loops

I am normally a maple user currently working with R, and I have a problem with correctly indexing variables.

Say I want to define 2 vectors, v1 and v2, and I want to call the nth element in v1. In maple this is easily done: 
v[1]:=some vector,

and the nth element is then called by the command 
v[1][n]. 
How can this be done in R? The actual problem is as follows:

I have a sequence M (say of length 10, indexed by k) of simulated negbin variables. For each of these simulated variables I want to construct a vector X of length M[k] with entries given by some formula. So I should end up with 10 different vectors, each of different length. My incorrect code looks like this

```
sims<-10
M<-rnegbin(sims, eks_2016_kasko*exp(-2.17173), 840.1746)
for(k in 1:sims){
                 x[k]<-rep(NA,M[k])
                 X[k]<-rep(NA,M[k])
for(i in 1:M[k]){x[k][i]<-runif(1,min=0,max=1)
                  if(x[k][i]>=0 & x[i]<=0.1056379){
                    X[k][i]<-rlnorm(1, 6.228244, 0.3565041)}
  else{
    X[k][i]<-rlnorm(1, 8.910837, 1.1890874)
  }
 }
}
```

The error appears to be that x[k] is not a valid name for a variable. Any way to make this work?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `[` is used for indexing, so `x[i]` extracts the `i`th element from a vector `x`. So `x[k]` is indeed not a valid variable name. In order to help you, a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162) would be very useful. It seems that your example code would be reproducible, if you provided `eks_2016_kasko` and `rnegbin()` or `M`.

Comment: Does `rnegbin()` come from the `MASS` package?

Comment: eks_2016_kasko=486689.1.

Correct, rnegbin is indeed from the MASS package :)

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your R script slightly to get it working and make it reproducible. To do this I had to assume that `eks_2016_kasko` was an integer value of `10`.

```
require(MASS)
sims<-10

# Because you R is not zero indexed add one
M<-rnegbin(sims, 10*exp(-2.17173), 840.1746) + 1

# Create a list
x <- list()
X <- list()
for(k in 1:sims){
    x[[k]]<-rep(NA,M[k])
    X[[k]]<-rep(NA,M[k])
    for(i in 1:M[k]){
        x[[k]][i]<-runif(1,min=0,max=1)
    if(x[[k]][i]>=0 & x[[k]][i]<=0.1056379){
        X[[k]][i]<-rlnorm(1, 6.228244, 0.3565041)}
    else{
        X[[k]][i]<-rlnorm(1, 8.910837, 1.1890874)
    }
    }
```

This will work and I think is what you were trying to do, BUT is not great R code. I strongly recommend using the [lapply family](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) instead of `for` loops, learning to use data.table and parallelisation if you need to get things to scale. Additionally if you want to read more about indexing in R and subsetting Hadley Wickham has a comprehensive break down [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with a few remarks and then show you, how your problem can be solved using R.

- In R, there is most of the time no need to use a `for` loop in order to assign several values to a vector. So, for example, to fill a vector of length 100 with uniformly distributed random variables, you do something like:

  ```
  set.seed(1234)
  x1 <- rep(NA, 100)
  for (i in 1:100) {
    x1[i] <- runif(1, 0, 1)
  }
  ```

  (`set.seed()` is used to set the random seed, such that you get the same result each time.) It is much simpler (and also much faster) to do this instead:

  ```
  x2 <- runif(100, 0, 1)
  identical(x1, x2)
  ## [1] TRUE
  ```

  As you see, results are identical.
- The reason that `x[k]<-rep(NA,M[k])` does not work is that indeed `x[k]` is not a valid variable name in R. `[` is used for indexing, so `x[k]` extracts the element `k` from a vector `x`. Since you try to assign a vector of length larger than 1 to a single element, you get an error. What you probably want to use is a list, as you will see in the example below.

So here comes the code that I would use instead of what you proposed in your post. Note that I am not sure that I correctly understood what you intend to do, so I will also describe below what the code does. Let me know if this fits your intentions.

```
# define M
library(MASS)
eks_2016_kasko <- 486689.1
sims<-10
M<-rnegbin(sims, eks_2016_kasko*exp(-2.17173), 840.1746)

# define the function that calculates X for a single value from M
calculate_X <- function(m) {
  x <- runif(m, min=0,max=1)
  X <- ifelse(x > 0.1056379, rlnorm(m, 6.228244, 0.3565041),
              rlnorm(m, 8.910837, 1.1890874))
}
# apply that function to each element of M
X <- lapply(M, calculate_X)
```

As you can see, there are no loops in that solution. I'll start to explain at the end:

- `lapply` is used to apply a function (`calculate_X`) to each element of a list or vector (here it is the vector `M`). It returns a list. So, you can get, e.g. the third of the vectors with `X[[3]]` (note that `[[` is used to extract elements from a list). And the contents of `X[[3]]` will be the result of `calculate_X(M[3])`.
- The function `calculate_X()` does the following: It creates a vector of `m` uniformly distributed random values (remember that `m` runs over the elements of `M`) and stores that in `x`. Then it creates a vector `X` that contains log normally distributed random variables. The parameters of the distribution depend on the value `x`.

Comment: Actually, your code gives vectors of the correct length, but each entry takes only one of two different values , e.g.  for X[[3]][3]=X[[3]][9]=X[[3]][550]=42775.2. So it looks as if it uses the same simulation again and again.

Comment: You are right! In the second call of `rlnorm` I had written a `1` instead of `m`. It's corrected now. Sorry about that!